# removing a particular character in a string in linux sh scripts

Tags: string, shell, substring, sh, special-characters

I am making a method for custom job creation in a crontab manager where it prompts the user for hours/min/month/date etc and then creates the first half of the crontab command using * when necesary or the user given value. My problem is with the asterix * character. Being a special character is causes unwanted behaviour. My solution was to use `\*`  and try to remove the `\` from the completed string after its been put together and before I add the command part. I cannot figure out how to remove all the `\` from the string; ive tried `$string//\`  and `$string//"\"` and other variations of it. Ive also tried `newstring=$("oldstring" | \  )` and variations of it. Initially i was just building a string with a * or a variable containing it `($string$star$string)`. Also tried the `${string}*${string}` approach. I am now stuck as to how to remove every \ from a string that looks somethinglike*: `00  \* \* 09 \*`

the whole method is this:

```
echo "When would you like the job to occur? A for all"

echo "On which hour? A for every hour"
read hour

echo "On which minute? A for every minute"
read min
space=" "
if [ "$min" = "A" ]
then
minstring="Every minute"
minout="\*"
else
minstring=$min
minout=$min
fi

if [ "$hour" = "A" ]
then
hourstring="Every Hour"
hourout="\*"
else
hourstring=$hour
hourout=$hour
fi

timestring=$hourstring$space$minstring
frequency=$minout$space$hourout$space

echo "For which month 01-12. Or any other character for every month"
read month
monthout=$month
case $month in

01)
monthstring="January"
;;
02)
monthstring="February"
;;
03)
monthstring="March"
;;
04)
monthstring="April"
;;
05)
monthstring="May"
;;
06)
monthstring="June"
;;
07)
monthstring="July"
;;
08)
monthstring="August"
;;
09)
monthstring="September"
;;
10)
monthstring="October"
;;
11)
monthstring="November"
;;
12)
monthstring="December"
;;
*)
monthstring=" Every month "
monthout="\*"
;;
esac


echo "On partiular dates(date) or days of the week(dow) Or everyday(A)"
read choice
case $choice in
date)
echo "Which dates: "
read date


datestring="Date(s) ${date}"

frequency+="$date$space$monthout$space\*$space"
;;
dow)
echo "Which days. 1 for monday:"
read days
daystring="days ${days}"
frequency+="\*$space$monthout$space$days$space"
;;
A)
daystring="Every Day"
frequency+="\*$space$month\*$space"
;;
*)
echo "invalid input"
;;
esac

echo "Enter your command for: $timestring"
echo $monthstring
echo "On $daystring"
read command

fullcommand=$frequency$command
echo $fullcommand
```

Comment: Are you using `sh`? can you run `bash`?

Comment: Aside, a reduction might be possible for the first `case` block, eg: `monthstring=$(date --date="2000-${month}-03" "+%B" 2> /dev/null)`; follow with checking `$?`

Comment: I can't use bash

Comment: Milag's answer was useful but i need to append the string with the command and then add it to crontab.

Comment: The original posted code shows various append;  can another append be added?  Provide details if stuck on something new.

Comment: appending anything to it just brings me back to the same problem. Only works with     trim \""$trim"\"    Im not able to add the command on to the trimmed string to then add to crontab. it still reads the * as a special character and prints the contents of the directory.

Comment: Ignore the outer `\"` pair used for demo purpose; consider the results from an unquoted `echo $xyz_with_stars` versus `echo "$xyz_with_stars"`; same when assigning

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working this is what i used  (the cut version) ```trim=$(echo "$frequency" | tr -d '\134')



read command

trim+="$command"
echo "$trim"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# example, trim with "tr"
str='00  \* \* 09 \*'
echo str \""$str"\"
trim=$(echo "$str" | tr -d '\134')
echo trim \""$trim"\"
```